# Binary Search with matrix

Tags: c, matrix, search, count, binary

I have a matrix:
[pic of matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKYl1.png)

I need to count with Binary Search how many capital letters are on matrix.
This is my code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define N 4
#define M 4
int bigLetters(char** mat);
int main()
{
    char mat[M][N] = { 'H','i','k','o','A','B','x','z','F','K','Z','m','A','d','e','f' };
    printf("%d", bigLetters(mat));
    return 0;
}
int bigLetters(char** mat)
{
    int i, cnt = 0;
    int low, high, mid;
    for (i = 0;i < M;i++)
    {
        low = 0;
        high = N - 1;
        while (low <= high)
        {
            mid = (low + high) / 2;
            if (mat[i][mid] >= 'a' && mat[i][mid] <= 'z') high = mid - 1;
            else if (mat[i][mid] >= 'A' && mat[i][mid] <= 'Z' && mat[i][mid + 1] >= 'a' && mat[i][mid + 1] <= 'z')
            {
                cnt = cnt + mid + 1;
                low = high + 1;
            }
            else low = mid + 1;
        }
    }
    return cnt;
}
```

The program is crashing in first If sentence.
[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WiMWx.png)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are ignoring 2 serious warnings: https://ideone.com/GshmwO
Your array initialization misses some `{ }` and a `char (*) []` is incompatible to a `char**`

Comment: I just changed (char** mat) to (char mat[][N]) and it works. Thank you!

Comment: Consider checking the `isupper` and `islower` functions

Comment: @mch The first warning is not a “serious warning.”  In fact, I regularly leave out these braces as a part of my programming style.